# Cómo guardar correctamente un vídeo con opencv

Tags: python, linux, opencv

Estoy intentando seguir varios tutoriales de opencv usando un binding de Python para esta librería desde Linux pero me encuentro siempre con el mismo error.

El código que ejecuto es el siguiente:

```py
import cv2 as cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)


# Códec:
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('D','I','V','3')

out = cv2.VideoWriter('/home/ivan/Escritorio/output.avi', fourcc, 20.0, (640, 480))

# loop runs if capturing has been initialized.
while True:
    # reads frames from a camera
    # ret checks return at each frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # The original input frame is shown in the window
    cv2.imshow('Original', frame)

    out.write(frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('a'):
        break

# Close the window / Release webcam
cap.release()

# After we release our webcam, we also release the output
out.release()

# De-allocate any associated memory usage
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

La ventana con la captura de la webcam aparece correctamente. El problema está en que `output.avi`, el vídeo que obtengo de salida, siempre ocupa unos 5.5 KiB y no es reproducible.

He probado con diferentes códecs con el mismo resultado

```
# Códecs:
# fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'FFV1')
# fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
# fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX')
# fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIV3')
# fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('F','M','P','4')
# fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('D','I','V','3')
# fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('F','F','V','1')
```

Utilizo:

- KDE Neon User Edition 5.16 (basado en Ubuntu 18.04)
- Linux 5.3.1
- ffmpeg 3.4.6
- python3-opencv 3.2

Comment: Intentaste matchear la resolución de la captura exactamente? `(int(cap.get(3)),int(cap.get(4)))`

Comment: @DannyTalent buena observación! Da como resultado `(848, 480)`. He modificado `out`  para setearlo como `cv2.VideoWriter('/ruta', fourcc, 20.0, (848, 480))` pero obtengo el mismo resultado.

Comment: no veo en el código que estés haciendo `out.write(frame)`, entiendo que el `VideoWriter` debe "escribir" el video primero, no?

Comment: @DannyTalent has dado en el clavo con los dos comentarios. El fallo estaba en setear mal la resolución de la cámara. Omitir el `out.write(frame)` ha sido error mío al pegar el ejemplo. Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paso lo que conversamos en comentarios a una respuesta.

El problema aquí es que:

**1. Estás usando una resolución incorrecta** - Tienes que usar la resolución de tu entrada para la salida, por lo que quedaría:

```
out = cv2.VideoWriter('/home/ivan/Escritorio/output.avi', fourcc, 20.0, (int(cap.get(3)),int(cap.get(4))))
```

**2. No estás escribiendo la imagen** al archivo - hay que añadir un `out.write(frame)`

```
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('Original', frame)
    out.write(frame)
```